# What are searchers called?

Tags: meaning, phrases, idioms, american-english, british-english

Today my teacher taught me about using the prefix "re" to mean that you are doing something again. So for the word "Research" it means that you are doing some "search" again. Then, if we call them researchers, what are searchers called?

Comment: Just wait till you hear about rebound, rebar, replicate, redact, retort, response, remember, and many more =)

Comment: Not always. Note that the “re” in *republic* doesn't mean to redo something, it comes from the Latin word *res* meaning “matter”. The *res publica* were public affairs

Comment: Some interesting investigations on the topic: https://telescoper.wordpress.com/2012/03/08/the-meaning-of-research/

Answer (score 11):

In this case the prefix re- is an intensifier rather than the word element meaning *again, once more.* So the term you are looking for is “researcher”.

[Research](https://www.etymonline.com/word/research):

> 1590s, "investigate or study (a matter) closely, search or examine with continued care," from French recercher, from Old French recercher "seek out, search closely," from ***re-, here perhaps an intensive prefix*** (see re-), + cercher "to seek for,".

***[Re-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/re-?ref=etymonline_crossreference)***

> Often merely intensive, and in many of the older borrowings from French and Latin the precise sense of re- is forgotten, lost in secondary senses, or weakened beyond recognition, so that it has no apparent semantic content (receive, recommend, recover etc,)

(Etymonline)

Comment: Perfect. It is a mistake to assume that a prefix has only one, or indeed any, meaning.

Comment: refried beans are very fried beans, not doubly fried beans.

Comment: Dang @stannius, ruining Mitch Hedberg's joke! "I like refried beans. That's why I wanna try fried beans, because maybe they're just as good and we're just wasting time. You don't have to fry them again after all."

Comment: @Anton You're trying to tell me that Con-gress isn't the opposite of pro-gress?

Comment: @user3067860 amusing play on words, but no.